# AJAX/XMLHTTP Function issues

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I sincerely apologise in advance as this is my first go at AJAX. Simply put, I have two forms on a web page. At the click of a button the first form gets submitted. I use an onclick event to submit the second form BUT after making an xmlhtt request to the first form's database server to verify if the record is there BEFORE submiting the second form. I tried calling a PHP function via Javascript but was unsuccessful. Then I as told AJAX is the the way. But I never knew what kind of animal that is. So I followed an online tutorial and came up with the following:

```
<script>
function verypost() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  }
  else  { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             var gigs = this.responseText;
                if (gigs!="")
                      { document.getElementById("ukpform").submit(); }

                 else { alert ("Very sorry , we encountered a slight error in uploading your ad. Can you please try again? Many thanks.");  }
       }

           else {alert("We are sorry your ad did not post successfully. It may be due to javascript being disabled in your browser. Please can you try again making sure javascript is enabled on your computer. Thanks"); }
        };

       xmlhttp.open("GET", "postchecker.php?gt="+<?php echo $SRID ?>, true);
       xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>


<?php

$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$result; $db="freemar5_fmsdb";
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'fmxxxx','hhdhdhfhdh');
if (! $link) die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($db , $link) or die("Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT  ID FROM msadtable WHERE  ItemNo='$q'" ) or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ;
    $id = $row['ID'];

echo $id;

mysql_close($link);

?>


<input id="ukp" name="ukp" type="button" class="telbt" value="->>  PAY and SUBMIT  <<-" onclick="verypost();" >
```

The form is not submiting, I'm virtually certain there are errors but I can't figure them out. Any ideas will be very much appreciated.
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I wholeheartedly recommend *not* to re-implement the functionality that is readily available from multiple, tried-and-tested libraries. Use an Ajax library (like `request.js` https://github.com/request/request), your time learning something like this will be infinitely better invested.

Comment: I also recommend not to post your database passwords online.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to all you gurus out there.

I presume my question was unpopular so I started thinking about other options and I succeeded. I have been able to use PHP Session Variables to achieve my purpose. I set a session variable on the landing page which will be updated/overwritten by a small PHP code if it finds the data posted from the first form in the database. I then added a small script on the form which checks if the Session variable has been updated before it submits the second form. If not updated, it means the data from the first form was not successfully inserted in the database, so the second form will not be submitted.

Anyways, thanks to you all.

Answer (score -1):

Please use jQuery rather than JavaScript.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'postchecker.php',
    data: {name: 'abhi'},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```